# Rest-Client will not install for Ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems, installation

I am trying to run a Ruby app with the rest-client gem install. I keep getting the error message:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/windows/root_certs.rb:2:in `require': cannot load such file -- ffi (LoadError)
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/windows/root_certs.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/windows.rb:7:in `require_relative'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/windows.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient.rb:16:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/rest-client.rb:2:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/rest-client.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from app.rb:6:in `require'
    from app.rb:6:in `<main>'

$ ./start ruby
Installing bundle
Starting server
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/windows/root_certs.rb:2:in `require': cannot load such file -- ffi (LoadError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/windows/root_certs.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/windows.rb:7:in `require_relative'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/windows.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient.rb:16:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/rest-client.rb:2:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/rest-client.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from app.rb:6:in `require'
        from app.rb:6:in `<main>'
```

However I am sure that the gem is install:

```
rest-client (2.0.0.rc2, 1.8.0)
rest-open-uri (1.0.0)
rest_client (1.8.3)
```

Does anyone know possibly what I am doing wrong in the installation process?

Comment: Its complaining about ffi gem, which probably is a dependency for one of your gems. Are you using bundler to install these gems? If not, try installing ffi gem, though you might end up with another error for another missing dependent gem, hence I would recommend installing these via Bundler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the that FFI was not install and was the reason I was getting error messages. unfortunately using

```
bundle install
```

did not install it correct and I had to install the gem manually (which takes much longer than expected to install

```
 gem install ffi
```